# MySQL multiple conditions - concatenate or subquery?

Tags: mysql

We had a MySQL query that selected records and was required to also show Sold records for 60days before being removed from the shown results.
Logic was such that after changing a record from some invStatus to 1 which equals sold, we would filter it from our records after 60 days.

The problem is that if the filter is applied in a single query even active records are getting dropped if they are not updated within that 60 day window.

So how to select all records and then only filter a subset of those records based on date interval?

Should I select ALL the Ids and then filter those that are status sold and then apply the date interval in a subquery or run two queries and concatenate the two?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
SQLFiddle created that shows (10) records.

The goal is to not lose any invStatus = 0 but filter invStatus records that = 1 by NOT returning them if Update_date is older than 60 days from today

There are (7) records that have a invStatus = 0  (not Sold)
and (3) records that have invStatus = 1 (Sold)

```
 SELECT
     tblinventory.invId,
     tblinventory.`Update_date`,
     tblinventory.invStatus
 FROM
     tblinventory
 WHERE NOT (Update_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
 ORDER BYtblinventory.invId
```

results in (6) records

- 5 which are invStatus = 0
- 1 that is invStatus = 1

Should be

- (7) invStatus 0’s as they ALL should be present
- (1) invStatus = 1 that is within 60 days

SQLFiddle schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblinventory` (
   `invId` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `Update_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `invStatus` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
 ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 INSERT INTO `tblinventory` (`invId`,`Update_date`,`invStatus`) 
 VALUES 
 ("3777","2019-08-06 00:00:00","1"),
 ("3782","2019-08-30 00:00:00","0"),
 ("3820","2019-04-04 00:00:00","0"),
 ("3821","2019-03-21 00:00:00","1"),
 ("3835","2019-02-20 00:00:00","0"),
 ("3836","2019-06-30 00:00:00","1"),
 ("4035","2019-08-25 00:00:00","0"),
 ("4036","2019-09-01 00:00:00","0"),
 ("4037","2019-09-01 00:00:00","0"),
 ("4038","2019-09-01 00:00:00","0");
```

Query:

```
 SELECT
     tblinventory.invId,
     tblinventory.`Update_date`,
     tblinventory.invStatus
 FROM
     tblinventory
 WHERE NOT (Update_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND invStatus = 1
 ORDER BY
     tblinventory.invId
```

Comparative Query:

```
 WHERE NOT (Update_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KuYDHgYaNtaB8mMuatrz2/0

Comment: I understand, thanks for the suggestion as I created a sqlfiddle that illustrates the problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need a simple UNION ALL clause. Presumably invStatus <> 1 means non sold entities, You can try below query -

```
SELECT
    tblinventory.invId,
    tblinventory.`Update_date`,
    tblinventory.invStatus
FROM
    tblinventory
WHERE `invStatus` = 0 OR (Update_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
ORDER BY
    tblinventory.invId
```

Comment: Please review the latest sqlfiddle in and update to my original post that shows how we are not getting the expected results. We DO need to see Sold results but only those with a date in the past 60 days

Comment: SQL Fiddle is blank.

Comment: You dont need UNION just and OR condition

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, OR condition in where clause will not allow OP to use indexes in the query. Its preferred to use UNION ALL over OR clause.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Yes, I see it is not saving... I will make an update to the original post as sqlfiddle was quite helpful

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Update: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KuYDHgYaNtaB8mMuatrz2/0

Comment: You only need an OR condition in your query instead of an AND condition with the condition that your will not any indexes if there is any.

Comment: You can use a composite index.

Comment: and instead of NOT just reverse the < to >=

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Done now.